# Zend Framework: How to set default mail transport in configuration file?

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, email

I know that default mail transport could be set in bootstrap file but how to do it in app.ini file? Basically I want to use smtp transport on local windows system and regular mail transport on production server.

Edit: I'm already using [these settings](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.mail) in app.ini .

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your production server is *nix

```
[production]
resources.mail.transport.type = sendmail
[development : production]
resources.mail.transport.type = smtp
resources.mail.transport.host = smtp.example.com
```

Comment: i've tried using transport.type = smtp but i keep getting exceptions, Zend apparently cant load "smtp" i'm using Zend Framework 1.12

Answer (score 4):

you may looking for :

```
 resources.mail.transport.register = true ; True by default
```

full example : if you were in production you would use the first transport and in the development you would use development , pretty easy isn't

```
[production]
resources.mail.transport.type = smtp
resources.mail.transport.host = "smtp.example.com"
resources.mail.transport.auth = login
resources.mail.transport.username = myUsername
resources.mail.transport.password = myPassword
resources.mail.transport.register = true ; True by default

resources.mail.defaultFrom.email = john@example.com
resources.mail.defaultFrom.name = "John Doe"
resources.mail.defaultReplyTo.email = Jane@example.com
resources.mail.defaultReplyTo.name = "Jane Doe"


[development]
resources.mail.transport.type = smtp
resources.mail.transport.host = "smtp2.example.com"
resources.mail.transport.auth = login2
resources.mail.transport.username = myUsername
resources.mail.transport.password = myPassword
resources.mail.transport.register = true ; True by default

resources.mail.defaultFrom.email = john@example.com
resources.mail.defaultFrom.name = "John Doe"
resources.mail.defaultReplyTo.email = Jane@example.com
resources.mail.defaultReplyTo.name = "Jane Doe"
```

source : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html

Comment: This is exactly the source I've mentioned in 'Edit'. I think 'register' is not same as setting default. "When instantiating a transport, it's registered automatically to Zend_Mail. Though, by setting the transport.register directive to FALSE, this behaviour does no more occur. "

Comment: @understack , you could notice its result once you have multiple transports

Answer (score 0):

Beware that the following doesn't work, it throws an exception:

```
resources.mail.transport.type = smtp
```

We need to use Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp instead of only smtp. Please see below for the correct answer:

```
[production]
resources.mail.transport.type = sendmail
[development : production]
resources.mail.transport.type       = Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp
resources.mail.transport.host       = "smtp.server.com"
resources.mail.transport.auth       = login
resources.mail.transport.username   = "myLogin"
resources.mail.transport.password   = "myPasswd"
```

Source: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9802